# How was Demo-2's Falcon 9 booster different from any other F9?

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9

According to [The Sum Of All Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches#Past_launches), the Falcon 9 has only twice (including the 2016 ground fire destroying the payload) failed to put the primary payload in orbit.

Thus, the May 30 2020 Demo-2 **launch** seemed pretty boring/routine. Was there something special about the rocket (not the payload; just the launcher)?

Comment: What makes you think it was different?

Comment: @Moo everyone is sooo excited over what to me seems a bog standard launch.  (**Launch**, not payload; I'me very excited about the payload.)  Thus, there must be something about the rocket that I don't know about.

Comment: Edited the question for timelessness and clarity.

Comment: `+1` this seems like a reasonable question, no need to down vote it

Comment: By way of analogy, consider what will happen when a vaccine against COVID-19 is finally released to the public. The cheers for that release will be much louder than were the cheers for this very important launch. Yet the public release of that vaccine will seem pretty boring / routine because by that point it has to be. Any changes in the vaccine would entail taking several steps back. The released vaccine will be exactly the same as what was tested in multiple prior phases of clinical trials. The public release will represent the culmination of that prior work, and will be widely cheered.

Comment: Completing the analogy, the launch on Saturday represented the culmination of a decade's worth of prior work. During that decade, SpaceX had to make modifications to the Falcon 9 to make it safe for humans and then prove to NASA that it was indeed safe for humans. One small part of that was to make Falcon 9 launches at least appear to be boring / routine.

Comment: @uhoh - Some questions are worth downvoting. This is one of them.

Comment: @DavidHammen. I don't follow your logic. Your first comments are the skeleton of a good answer. The last is a non-sequitur.

Comment: @DavidHammen "wide cheering" for a COVID vaccine is substantively different from hailing such a vaccine as an "unprecedented achievement" (which is what Gwynne Shotwell called the launch).  Bash me as pedantic, but for something to be unprecedented, something substantive must be "new". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unprecedented Otherwise, every child birth is an "unprecedented achievement", because **that specific child** has never been born before.  And yet family and friends cheer the birth.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There was no significant difference between the Falcon 9 booster (first stage B1058, on its first flight, as it happened) used for Demo-2 and other Block 5 Falcons.

The excitement was entirely due to the fact of it having a crewed payload, the first NASA astronauts to launch on a US rocket on US soil since 2011.

While Falcon 9 is shaping up to be a quite reliable launcher, no rocket launch is anything like perfectly safe; the stakes for the May 30 launch were higher than usual, and given the way the year is going, many people were braced for some kind of disaster to occur. For those people, there was a significant sense of relief after the first stage and second stage phases of the ascent completed. This sense was particularly acute for people of my age cohort, who were school-aged when the Challenger accident occurred in 1986; many of my friends commented on the tension they felt watching this launch.

Comment: I don't understand that mentality, but I accept that it exists.  If nothing better comes in the next 23 hours, I'll probably accept it.

Comment: Its worth noting that NASA needed stability in Falcon 9 configurations for a certain number of launches before they would sign off on a crewed launch, hence the rapid development up to Block 5 and then a plateau

Comment: Yes: Crewed payload. Adding to the tension was that just a day or two earlier a different commercial space/rocket company had a static test engine perform an unscheduled rapid disassembly (shortly after the test) in an a very exciting way.  Safe as we'd all like them to be rocket launches aren't entirely safe yet.  I distinctly remember the shock and numbness I felt passing as store in Central Square, Cambridge, MA and seeing a jagged trail on a TV in there on a day I knew the Challenger was launching.

Comment: @davidbak If you are referring to Starship and its explosion the day before, that one is also a SpaceX rocket, a different design meant to go straight to Mars.

Comment: @RonJohn you don’t understand the mentality of Americans being exited about launching American astronauts on an American rocket from America?

Comment: @walen - thank you, if i had that straight: even more tension, eh?

Comment: @Tim I'm an American, and I'm very glad the US finally is launching it's own people again instead of needing to go hat in hand to the Russians.  It's been **grossly over-hyped**, though.  "Unprecedented achievement", etc, etc.  Yes, things are different now (reusable first stage and capsule), but sending men to orbit in a capsule on top of a rocket has quite a lot of precedent.  The booster landing **four years ago** was unprecedented, as was the booster reuse **three years ago**.  This, though?  Lots of precedent.)

Comment: @RonJohn saying it’s not unprecedented doesn’t mean it’s not exciting. My birthday happens every year, and is incredibly precedented, but I still get exited for it!

Comment: @RonJohn This is the first manned spacecraft to reach orbit which is privately designed, owned and operated.  That is unprecedented.  Sure, you say that it's just a case of putting people in something that already works.  But in that case you also have to say there was a ton of precedent for Gagarin and Armstrong, because they were all "just" going where unmanned missions had already gone before.  And in however many years time, there'll be plenty of precedent on a manned mission to Mars, because the various rovers have already been there.

Comment: Upvote for "given the way the year is going" :-)

Comment: @RonJohn. I feel like calling precedented things "unprecedented" when done by Americans, overhyping everything and generally having "that mindset" are as American as it gets. I don't understand it either, but I can't seem to get away from it. It's good to know that some real progres soccasionally  happens despite this attitude.

Comment: @MadPhysicist and RonJohn - This was unprecedented. It represents the culmination of a nine-plus year long effort. NASA essentially paid \$3.4 billion for this launch and the payload. The follow-on launches, which will be precedented, will cost less than a tenth that.

Comment: @DavidHammen. Everything is unprecedented, depending on how you categorize it. πάντα ῥεῖ

Answer (score 30):

There were a number of minor upgrades that had to happen, primarily to allow for automatic flight failure detection to allow the abort system to activate. These fly on every flight now, but they didn't in the past. Past systems have included a wire that runs the length of the booster to detect if there is a fault, and there is almost certainly some software upgrades to detect issues, although I haven't been able to find the specific changes.

The biggest difference is not so much the booster, but the flight profile. In order to get humans to the ground safely in the event of an abort, a shallow trajectory is required. This results in a less fuel efficient trajectory, most noted by the booster having to land on a barge, while they could have launched the spacecraft in to a less abort friendly orbit and returned to the launch site. You can see the difference between a cargo dragon and a crew dragon at [this site](https://everydayastronaut.com/dragon-2-dm-2-spacexs-first-crewed-mission/).

[image]

Comment: Any detail on those "minor upgrades"?

Comment: I don't have any specifics, but they usually include running a wire the length of the rocket to detect breakup and software changes associated with this. Falcon 9 has an autonomous flight safety system, which is probably quite similar in a number of ways, so...

Comment: Can you provide references for the "a shallow trajectory is required"? AFAIK **starliner** from boeing will certainly do a shallow trajectory; Crew Dragon, last I've heard, actually does a steeper profile, bringing astronauts to orbit as fast as possible. I've tried to find some official sources but I cannot find any document specifying the flight profile one way or the other.

Comment: It is a shallower trajectory, because otherwise they would do a RTLS for the booster. They have to be shallower to support an abort at any time, if you go straight up it's really hard to slow down quick enough, to slow down via atmosphere you have to spread it out a bit.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. I read before that DM-2 has a steeper profile, not a shallower one, compared to crew dragon missions. I don't know exactly why: I can think of different factors, and some seem to favor a steep trajectory and some a shallow. I think Everyday Astronaut switched the profiles. See the profiles on flightclub.io: CRS-20 climbs to about 160 km (https://flightclub.io/result/2d?id=0ebad692-0e09-44f0-a610-ec6568bfa95d), while DM-2 climbs to 216 km (https://flightclub.io/result/2d?code=DEM2)

Comment: I had a closer look at the page where the image above comes from (https://everydayastronaut.com/dragon-2-dm-2-spacexs-first-crewed-mission/), and it seems the captions in the image don't match the caption under the image. Something went wrong somewhere.